# Changing dictionary values based on matches between dictionary keys and a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to supply a hex color code to a dictionary based on a not equal to condition. I have the following data:

```
my_list = [1,3,5]
my_dict = {0 : '#a2bd62', 1 : '#9930ad', 2 : '#41c65d', 3 : '#9359d9', 4 : '#4667e6', 5 : '#c95eda'}
```

Now, for all the dictionary keys NOT IN my_list I want the values of that particular key/valur pair to be : `'#A9A9A9'`.

My current solution loops over all items in list and then over all keys, however this solution is flawed as all values in my dict ends up being `'#A9A9A9'`:

```
for item in my_list:
    for key,value  in my_dict.items():
        if item != key:
            my_dict[key] = '#A9A9A9'
```

Anyone able to offer a solution?

Comment: You're testing the keys against each value in your list one by one in turn, so for each key you'll make three comparisons. Well, the key can only be equal to *one* value, so it'll fail *at least two* of those comparisons… You'll want to test whether `key not in my_list`…!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first be looping over `my_dict.items()` not `my_list`, note that you just want to check if a given key is `in` the list (use the `in` operator!)

So here's one way using a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_set = set([1,3,5])
my_dict = {0 : '#a2bd62', 1 : '#9930ad', 2 : '#41c65d', 3 : '#9359d9', 
           4 : '#4667e6', 5 : '#c95eda'}

{k:v if k in my_set else '#A9A9A9' for k,v in my_dict.items()}
# {0: '#A9A9A9', 1: '#9930ad', 2: '#A9A9A9', 3: '#9359d9', 4: '#A9A9A9', 5: '#c95eda'}
```

Or with a regular `for` loop:

```
d = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if k in my_set:
        d[k] = v
    else:
        d[k] = '#A9A9A9'
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this answer due to the flexibility in the regular for loop (i.e. being able to parse a value if k in my_set = True. I'm sure this will be useful at some point as well).

Answer (score 1):

you can make set difference between your keys and `my_list`:

```
my_list = [1,3,5]
my_dict = {0 : '#a2bd62', 1 : '#9930ad', 2 : '#41c65d', 3 : '#9359d9', 4 : '#4667e6', 5 : '#c95eda'}
val = '#A9A9A9'

for k in set(my_dict.keys()).difference(my_list):
    my_dict[k] = val
```

this is O(M) time complexity approach (where M is the number of keys that are not in `my_lsit`), a bit faster than searching for each key from your `my_dict` in the list `my_list`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
for key,value in my_dict:
    if (key in my_list):
        continue
    my_dict[key] = '#A9A9A9'
```